# @CompileStatic: automatic type cast possible?

Tags: groovy, switch-statement, type-inference, instanceof, compile-static

Is it possible that the below code can be compiled with `@CompileStatic`?

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class CompileStaticTest {

    List<Number> numbers = []

    void addWithCase(something) {
        switch (something) {
            case Integer: numbers << something; break // compile error
            case Float:   numbers << something; break // compile error
        }
    }   

    void addWithInstanceof(something) {
        if (something instanceof Integer) {
            numbers << something // compile error
        }

        if (something instanceof Float) {
            numbers << something // compile error
        }
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```
test = new CompileStaticTest()

test.addWithCase(11)
test.addWithCase(12f)
test.addWithCase('13')

test.addWithInstanceof(21)
test.addWithInstanceof(22f)
test.addWithInstanceof('23')

println test.numbers
```

Currently there are compile errors:

```
[Static type checking] - Cannot call <T> java.util.List <Number>#leftShift(T) with arguments [java.lang.Object]
```

The type of *something* is known by `switch-case` or `instanceof` so the cast could be done automatically, no? Maybe I am just presenting a too simple example and implementing the requested functionality is not suitable for more complex code.

Comment: As far as I understood You suggest that `something` object should be automatically casted to appropriate `Number` subclass?

Comment: Exactly. The question is, if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug, because the following is allowed:

```
if (something instanceof Integer) {
    something.intValue()
}
```

Maybe filling a [JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY)?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug but a new feature for `@CompileStatic`. Currently it's a bit unclear what is already supported. So instead of filing a new ticket I'd first like to check if it's feasible.